# Vue3 : Cant osberve changes on a variable defined on external JS file

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I've an external script that is imported on a mainComponent.vue, it manages some processes and what I can't do so far is to listen the change of a boolean variable that sets the end of the program:

**externalScript.js:**

```
export let kmcFinished = false;
export getVariables;
...
export function endProgram(){
...
kmcFinished = true;
}

export function getVariables(){
return {
...*other variables*
kmcFinished
}
}
```

**MainComponent.vue**

```
import {getVariables} from "@/components/js/externalScript.js"; 
... 
<script> 
... 
computed:{       
getFinishState(){        
  console.log(getVariables().kmcFinished); // Here console shows only once false value
  return getVariables().kmcFinished;       
}     
},     

watch: {     
getFinishState: {       
   handler(newVal){         
      console.log(newVal); // This console.log never executes, why?         
      if (newVal) {         
         saveSessionState(); // So this never gets done, as never receives 'true'         
       }       
    },       
    deep:true     
}   
}, 
... 
</script>
```

I've tried using update: instead but no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is, `getVariables()` creates a new property named `kmcFinished` on a new object initialized with the current value of your variable `kmcFinished`. The property will not change when `kmcFinished` changes (as you already observed).

But you can turn `kmcFinished` into a ref:

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
export const kmcFinished = ref(false);
...

export function endProgram(){
  ...
  kmcFinished.value = true;
}

export function getVariables(){
  return {
    ...
    kmcFinished
  }
}
```

Now you have a ref with an internal state, which you can observe and change through the `.value` property:

```
data:{
  isFinished: getVariables().kmcFinished // no need to put this into a computed
},
watch: {
  isFinished() {
    if (this.isFinished.value) {         
      ...          
    }
  }   
},
```

Btw. what you are doing looks very close to what [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) look like in Vue. Might be a good opportunity to get familiar with the structure.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. The only thing I could not implement as you suggested is the watch: method, have to change it as:

 watch: {
    isFinished: {
      handler(newVal){
        if ( newVal ) {
        console.log(newVal);
        this.Eureka();
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry, I forgot the `this` in `this.isFinished.value`. But passing in the value works just as well.